# Replace string in ASPX with build version at build time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild

Is there a way to look for a pattern in aspx/ascx files and replace it with a build number or some other token? I'm not interested in using reflection and setting the string at runtime. I'd like to go into the aspx/ascx files and replace the string using msbuild.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this what do you want to do? http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2010/12/07/simple-msbuild-configuration-updating-assemblies-with-a-version-number.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a project called [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) that contains a FileUpdateTask.  This should satisfy your requirement.  It allows you to make arbitrary text replacements using regular expressions.

```
<FileUpdate Files="MyWebPage.aspx"
            Regex="\<div id\=\'version\'\>(.*)\<\/div\>"
            ReplacementText="$(BuildVersion)" />
```

Please note that I haven't tested this regular expression.